# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchAll' of undefined in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am using Mobx-React to create a small app.  I have create a memberstore and have an asyn fetchAll method. (see below)

```
import {observable, action, computed} from 'mobx';

class MemberStore {
@observable members = [];
@observable isLoading = false;

@action async fetchAll() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/v1/members');
    const status = await response.status;
    if (status === 200) {
        this.members = response.json();
    } 
}
```

The front-end is a Contact page with the following code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Jumbotron from '../components/Jumbotron';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';

@inject('MemberStore')
@observer

class Contact extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.members.fetchAll();
}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = this.member.value;
    const email = this.email.value;
    // const email = this.email.value;
    this.props.MemberStore.addMember({name, email});
    this.member.value = '';
    this.email.value = '';
}
render() {
    const {MemberStore} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Jumbotron title="Contact Page" subtitle="You want to get in touch"/>
            <div className="container">
               <h2>You have {MemberStore.memberCount} members.</h2>

               <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ref={input => this.member = input }/>
                   <div>
                   <input type="text" placeholder= "Enter Your Email" ref={input => this.email = input }/>
                   </div>
                   <button>Submit</button>
               </form>
               <ul>
                {MemberStore.members.map(({name, email}, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                    <div>
                        name: {name}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        email: {email}
                    </div>
                    </li>
                ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

I am not sure if it should be `this.props.MemberStore.fetchAll()`  but gives me a different error of `TypeError: MemberStore.members.map is not a function`.
So wondering what I am doing wrong as I thought I am accessing the fetchAll() function in the MemberStore component.

Comment: "TypeError: MemberStore.members.map is not a function" means that MemberStore.members is not an array. Try to debug out what is the type of that variable.

Comment: But isn't ```@observable members = [];``` an array? Peter

Comment: When you update it here this.members = response.json(); members type can be updated. It depends what your api return or how the response can be accessed.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean Peter? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I mean JavaScript has dynamic typing. It does not mean anything how do you declare a variable. When you update the value of the members here: this.members = response.json(); The type will be whatever the resopse.json() function return.

Comment: I think I understand.  I have just gone back to the React part of the project after a break of a couple of days.  Should I have started the Ruby back end as well.

Comment: I am way off base Peter?

Comment: I can not tell you. I'm working with Redux. Mobx syntax is new to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184938/discussion-between-altbrian-and-peter).